# Resizing label based on text size - text shrinks when using sizeToFit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a label in a cell, and I need to place a button right next to it. The position of the button will depend on the amount of text in the label (single line)

I've done the following-

```
[cell.primaryTextLabel sizeToFit];
[cell.primaryTextLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
```

and this works great when there's less text (the label shrinks to the size of the text). But when there is a long string in the label, the label size seems to stay the same (as that specified in the xib) but the text shrinks and becomes unreadable.

How do I get the label to expand when there's a long string of text in the label?

Comment: try setting : `setNumberOfLines:0`

Comment: This makes it multi-line, but the text still shrinks. Is there a way I can get the label to expand but the text size to remain the same? Does the size in the xib indicate some sort of maximum, beyond which the label doesn't expand?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: If you don't want to shrink label than you need to set numberOfLines = 0 or else your button will go out of screen bounds.

Comment: No, I'm not using auto-layout.

Comment: Rushi, I don't want the text to shrink (the font seems to get smaller). This happens whether or not I set the numberOfLines to 0.

Comment: Can you please provide an image what exact output you want?

Comment: Try to Implement UISTACKVIEW this is best for content wise resizing

Comment: This link will gives you best example of UISTACKVIEW    http://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minimum fontsize of label, so that the size does not decrease beyond the readable size you specify

```
  [_myLabel setMinimumFontSize:10.0];
```

Comment: `minimumFontSize` property of `UILabel` is deprecated from iOS 6.0 onwards, so I've used `minimumScaleFactor` instead. Now, my text doesn't shrink as much, but gets truncated. Instead, I want the label to expand according to the text.

Answer (score 0):

This property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1.

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
```

A Boolean value indicating whether spacing between letters should be adjusted to fit the string within the label’s bounds rectangle.

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth
```